# Заменить empty элементы в массиве

Tags: javascript

Имеется массив:

```
a = [empty, data, data, empty, data]
```

Требуется заменить в этом массиве empty на []

Такой метод не работает

```
a = [2,3, empty ,4]
test = a.map(function(item) { 
    if(!item){
        return [];    
    }
    else {
        return item 
    }
 })
 // test = [2,3, empty ,4] после выполнения
```

Каким образом организовать проверку на empty в данном случае? (без использования сторонних библиотек)

Comment: empty это что, объект, строка?

Comment: @azlov массив объявлен как a = [2,3,,4]
typeof от a[2] отдаёт undefined

Comment: @R.Key, `map` не будет работать,потому что он итерируется только по существующим елементам.

Comment: `test = Array.from(a, e => typeof  e === 'undefined' ? [] : e)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map`, `forEach` и прочие встроенные методы пропускают пустые элементы массива. При этом, если туда непосредственно было присвоено значение `undefined` - увидят его:

```js
let arr = new Array(5);
arr[0] = undefined;

arr.map(e => console.log("map", e));

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log("for", arr[i]);
}
```

Используйте классический цикл:

```js
let arr = [2, 3, , , "moo"];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
  if (typeof arr[i] === "undefined") {
    arr[i] = [];
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```